Why would Google maps timeline be accurate with your places traveled majority of the time but it's always a visit that makes no sense
Location history is filling in places traveled all by itself showing this trip was taken here and I was at home all day or shows I was at a place overnight when I wasn't even there at all which was 4 miles from my house

I would double check what devices are tied to your Google account. See: https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity to see if you've logged into family member devices.

Related/possible duplicate: Google Maps Location History is showing an incorrect location
